# Image Button in C# Code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, button, imagebutton

I'm trying to set an image background in code-behind. I tried adding a background image to the button, but as soon as I hover over the button, the image disappears. To solve this, I have to write functions to override the button behavior, which is too much to do in code-behind.

I then use an alternative method, that is to add a button and an image separately to a grid cell. The issue is -- when I click on the image, the button won't trigger.

How do I make the button to have the **hover** and **pressed** effect, even when, the mouse is either hovering or presses the image on the button, but not the remaining area of the button?

Or hope someone can suggest me a better solution.Below is my code.

```
        InitializeComponent();
        Button playBtn = new Button();
        playBtn.Width = 60;
        playBtn.Height = 30;
        Image playIcon = new Image();
        playIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"PATH"));
        playIcon.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        playIcon.Height = 25;

        grid1.Children.Add(playBtn);
        grid1.Children.Add(playIcon);

        Grid.SetColumn(playBtn, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(playBtn, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(playIcon, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(playIcon, 0);
```

thanks for everyone input, after digging more into it, it sort of work out. What I did is add a **Grid** to **Button.Content** then add the image to the Grid. And using **Opacity** to add the grey out effect for **IsEnable** false state. Below I post my code, hope someone find it useful or improve on:

```
    Button playBtn = new Button();
    Image playIcon = new Image();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Grid grid2 = new Grid();
        RowDefinition grid2_row1 = new RowDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition grid2_col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        grid2.RowDefinitions.Add(grid2_row1);
        grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(grid2_col1);

        playBtn.Width = 60;
        playBtn.Height = 30;
        playBtn.Click += playBtn_Click;

        playIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://PATH..."));
        playIcon.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        playIcon.Height = 25;

        playBtn.Content = grid2;
        grid2.Children.Add(playIcon);

        grid1.Children.Add(playBtn);

        Grid.SetRow(playIcon, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(playIcon, 0);
    }

    public void playBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        playBtn.IsEnabled = false;
        playIcon.Opacity = 0.3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below links

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2007/10/31/wpf-control-development-3-ways-to-build-an-imagebutton.aspx

http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/01/create-wpf-image-button-through-attached-properties

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/91df562f-414c-4326-ac65-42ef301b5f8f/

Answer (score 1):

Buttons in WPF have different states = "normal", "mouse over" and "pressed" are three.

When you create the button you are setting up it's "normal" state. You also need to set the "mouse over" state to have the same image as well.

Comment: How do I bind the mouse_over state of the image to the mouse_over state of the button?

Comment: @KMC - I have code that does this at home, I'll see if I can dig it out and post it later today.

Comment: @ChrisF - thanks, that will be very helpful. My other concern is if I were to get the same button effect when I hover or press the image on the button, I will need to rewrite the same Normal, Mouse_Over and Presses state event that a default button has. Or can I inherit the default mouse event class in my new mouse event class?

Comment: @KMC - there are different ways of doing this. One is to edit the button template code in XAML. You shouldn't have to duplicate code.

Comment: @ChrisF - both the button and image is generated in run-time. No XAML to work with. With code behind, I have no clue what step should I take.

Comment: @KMC - OK - I'll have to check my code when I get home to see if it applies or can be modified to your circumstance.

Comment: @ChrisF - I have edited my question with a solution. Let me know if that can be improved or have problems with it.