# Button image content wont show except after step by step debug

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm at a loss here...

Just trying to get an image showing on a button from codebehind. The image is being fed by the user in a dialog and is copied in the executable folder.

```
            Image buttonImage = new Image();
            buttonImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Name + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
            buttonImage.Height = 100;

            Content = buttonImage;
```

It actually does work but *only when stepping with the debugger*. The code abode is from within my own Button control in a desperate attempt to try [a slightly different way](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/knom/2007/10/31/wpf-control-development-3-ways-to-build-an-imagebutton/) and see if the result would be different.

From what I've found, most people recommend setting Button Content Templates and use databinding from there, but it's not an option here.

Any idea why that wouldn't show up properly?

Thanks for any help you can give.

**EDIT:** [this and the answer links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389769/image-button-in-c-sharp-code-behind#5389896) have been studied to no avail

**EDIT2:** It's really when I'm changing a value within the Image Control at runtime that the image shows up afterward. I obviously tried to put the option changed directly into the code but it didn't work... (changed the stretch mode to be sure it wasn't a scale issue)

Comment: The image "is copied in the executable folder", why are you doing that? The application may not always have write access to that folder, e.g. when it is installed in the standard programs folder and run by a non-priviledged user.

Comment: When are you calling the function? With the initialize components?

Comment: @Clemens just for the sake of simplicity, this is for an exercise I'm giving to a GUI 101 group

Comment: @NassifBousaba the function is called from an overloaded Name setter in my own inherited Button control, because the image might be changed during the button lifetime and depends on the Name... I know that's not an optimal behaviour but that's for the sake of demonstration. 

It didn't work from constructor neither though, and everything happens after InitializeComponent()